# ASP.NET MVC3 Custom Validation Message Display

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Is there a way in ASP.NET MVC3 to customize the result of the Html.ValidationMessageFor(...) method? For example add an image next to the error text or similar...
But I want to be able to change the image whether the validation is successful or not...

Answer (score 11):

You can see that the error is wrapped with a Css Class, all you need to do is use that Css Class at your own will.

The default MVC3 contains in the `styles.css`

```
/* Styles for validation helpers
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.field-validation-error
{
    color: #ff0000;
}

.field-validation-valid
{
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.validation-summary-errors
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.validation-summary-valid
{
    display: none;
}
```

just add your images there.

Answer (score 7):

Yup 
U can write ur own extension to do so

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");
        div.AddCssClass("aside");

        string modelName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        ModelState state = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[modelName];
        if (state != null)
            if ((state.Errors != null) && (state.Errors.Count > 0))
                div.AddCssClass("invalid");
            else 
                div.AddCssClass("valid");

        div.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).ToString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(div.ToString());
    }
```

Then use something like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

And lastly u need to define ur css for invalid and aside class to customize how the error looks.

Comment: Unfortunatly this was not what I need. I can't find a way to use this to display different images depending on whether the validation succeeded or not (like a check and an X icon)...

Comment: @nogola : sure u can...just add the required style on the class invalid
you can also modify the code to add a different class when there is no error...as shown in the edit above

Comment: Also...i have just used an example of div..u can use anything else that u want to show next to the form editor

Comment: No, because this extension method is only called on page load to set up the initial html. After that all validation is done through the jquery-validate-plugin and no server code is called...